# What factors have the greatest effects on the yield from steam distillation of ginger?

Tags: home-experiment, distillation

I have a modest home lab setup that I use primarily for steam distillation of plant matter to extract essential oils. My yields are typically at or below the low end of estimates given by different sources, but understandably so since I'm working with very small amounts (e.g. I recently got a 0.55% yield from 217g of thyme; cf. Holmes 2016, 2019 which both list typical yields between 0.67-1.0%).

However I recently tried distilling ginger which according to multiple sources typically has a fairly high yield (cf. Holmes 2016: 3.3-5.0%; Malle & Schmickl 2015: 1.9-2.6%; Möller 2018: ~4%). I used 378g of fresh ginger from a local grocery store, I chopped it coarsely, and filled the boiling flask with about 500mL distilled water. But after 4.5 hours, I ended up with <0.5mL of oil—a yield of ~0.1%.

After the first run, I even tried putting the ginger in a food processor to make it a bit finer and ran it again with another ~350mL water for 1.5 hours but didn't get enough oil for it even to separate.

In all I ended up with about 550mL of hyrdosol and ~0.25mL of essential oil.

This was the setup I used:

[image: Home distillation setup]

#### TL;DR: So my question is, what are the most likely factors that could have reduced the yield to such an extent?

I know fresh ginger from the grocery store may not have been the best choice for the purposes of extracting essential oils, so next time I'll try getting dried ginger intended for therapeutic uses, but other than that, I'm not sure what else to do differently next time.

##### Works cited

- Holmes, Peter. 2016. Aromatica: a clinical guide to essential oil therapeutics, vol. 1: applications and profiles.
- Holmes, Peter. 2019. Aromatica: a clinical guide to essential oil therapeutics, vol. 2: principles and profiles.
- Malle, Bettina & Helge Schmickl. 2015. The essential oil maker's handbook. (Trans. by Paul Lehmann)
- Möller, Kai. 2018. Tabletop distilling: how to make spirits, essences, and essential oils with small stills.

Comment: Nice setup. I would recommend a heating mantle. A question, did you ever tried simply putting the ginger on the boiler? This at least will shorten the path. But I have no experience on steam distillation except for a couple of time as student and long ago. The latter is a question rather than a suggestion.

Comment: @Alchimista I haven't tried that yet but am planning to next weekend. If it makes a huge difference I'll post an update.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン The sources don't go into a great amount of detail about the processes involved other than to say whether they used fresh vs. dried or simple vs. steam. Malle & Schmickl sometimes also provide information about when to collect the plant matter, but as I'm mainly using things you can find on Amazon or a grocery store, that's a bit out of my control.

Comment: You have not described the oil separation. Do you apply extraction/evaporation for oil/water separation? Or centrifugation of emulsion? Part of the essential oil can be dissolved or can form stable emulsion.

Comment: @Poutnik For separation I just let the oil/hydrosol settle in a separatory funnel and empty them into separate containers.

Comment: I remember my lab practice in 1985 of isolation of essential oil from cloves. After distillation, there was very fine and like stable oil emulsion. After extraction to CHCl3 and solvent evaporation I got about 1-2 mL of oil. Without extraction or centrifugation, it could help to dissolve enough NaCl, what may help in emulsion separation.